# No animation, endless loop in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create what I thought would be a simple Canvas to move a point from A to B using `requestAnimationFrame`.

http://jsfiddle.net/p1L81yk4/1/

Unfortunately it is not showing anything, and the animation loop seems to be headed towards infinity.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? And is there a flag I can create to show when the animation should stop?

```
var startX = 10,
startY = 10;
var endX = 200,
endY = 350;

var speed = 1;
var dx = endX - startX;
var dy = endY - startY;
var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
var moves = distance / speed;
var xunits = (dx / moves);
var yunits = (dy / moves);
var posit = {
    x: startX,
    y: startY 
};


var fps = 60;
var delay = 1000 / 30;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(startX, startY);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

function move() {
    startX += dx;
    startY += dy;

    console.log(posit);

    if (moves > 0) {
        moves++;
        posit.x += xunits;
        posit.y += yunits;
    }
}

var start = 0;

function animate() {
    running = true;
    var current = new Date().getTime(),
    delta = current - start;

    if (delta >= delay) {
        move();
        draw();
        start = new Date().getTime();
    }

    anim = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Comment: I would have a better look into trig as it will simplify your code immensely, allow you to calculate x and y values at an angle with having to make this strange interpolation of x and y values (in essence you are using _way_ too many variables to accomplish a very simple task with trigonometry). SOHCAHTOA will be your friend.

Comment: Use `Date.now()` method instead of `new Date().getTime()` expression. Also I suggest you to read [this article](http://jlongster.com/Making-Sprite-based-Games-with-Canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic trigonometry you can make the entire code look and read easier, with less up front variables. I still need to set quite a lot of variables here, but you would want to mostly calculate them on the fly (which means you would have to move things like angle, from and to value and distance into the `myDraw()` function).

```js
var myCanvas   = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var myContext  = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    myContext.fillStyle = '#000';
// Values expressed as x, y, positions
var fromValue  = [300,20];
var toValue    = [100,100];
// time expressed in Milliseconds
var time       = 5000;
var start      = Date.now();
// Get the angle with the arctangent function
// tan(angle)  = opposite / adjacent => atan(opposite / adjacent) = angle
// atan2 is used because you can pass it the lengths and it takes care of
// some negative edge cases.
var angle      = Math.atan2(toValue[0] - fromValue[0], toValue[1] - fromValue[1]);
// Basic distance because.. Pythagoras. (a^2 = sqrt(b^2 + c^2))
var distance   = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(toValue[0] - fromValue[0], 2) + Math.pow(toValue[1] - fromValue[1], 2));

function myDraw(now){
  
  // The max distance can be divided by the total time, multiplied by the time that has passed
  var t = (distance / time * (now - start));
  var x = fromValue[0] + Math.sin(angle) * t;
  var y = fromValue[1] + Math.cos(angle) * t;
  
  // Clear the canvas by resetting its width
  myCanvas.width = myCanvas.width;
  
  // Draw the arc at position x and y
  myContext.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  myContext.fill();
  
  // Return false if the animation is done.
  if(now < start + time) return true;
  else return false;
}

function myAnimate(){
  // Keep executing as long as myDraw() returns true
  if(myDraw(Date.now())) window.requestAnimationFrame(myAnimate);
}

myAnimate();
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Nicely commented, and this is a whole lot more straightforward than the examples I had been seeing elsewhere.

Comment: I haven't seen a version which used the angle before -- just the distance and "translate". Is there an advantage to this approach?

Comment: With the angle you get more versatility - trigonometry is really good for this kind of thing. The main advantage for me is that describing a result in angle and distance feels much more intuitive than giving two coordinates, and you can turn coordinates into angles. And trigonometry is just a nice thing to know (:

Comment: I did come across a similar problem to the solution below: you cannot travel due north or south. If the coordinates are, for example, (100,20) to (300,20), nothing happens.

Comment: @Tyler330 sorry about that, there were some errors with the code. First of, the x value is calculated with the sinus, not the cosinus. Secondly I added the wrong basenumber for the y value (it has to start at the Y value and I set it to x as well). Check amended code with amended coordinates to see it go in a wildly different direction this time. This should work with every value now (:

Answer (score 2):

- You should not use `save` and `restore`, these functions is for saving and restoring the images.
- You should translate `posit.x` and `posit.y` instead of `startX` and `startY`.
- You are changing `startX` and `startY` which is not reasonable.
- You need a `if` to determinate if or if not to continue aniamtion.

Which ends up with a working code:

```js
    var canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
        ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
    var startX = 10,
        startY = 10;
    var endX = 200,
        endY = 350;

    var speed = 2;
    var dx = endX - startX;
    var dy = endY - startY;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var moves = distance / speed;
    var xunits = (dx / moves);
    var yunits = (dy / moves);
    var posit = {
        x: startX,
        y: startY
    };


    var fps = 60;
    var delay = 1000 / 60;

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
        //ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(posit.x, posit.y);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.translate(-posit.x, -posit.y);
        //ctx.restore();
    }

    function move() {
        //startX += dx;
        //startY += dy;

        //console.log(posit);

        if (moves > 0) {
            moves++;
            posit.x += xunits;
            posit.y += yunits;
        }

    }

    var start = 0;

    function animate() {
        running = true;
        var current = new Date().getTime(),
            delta = current - start;

        if (delta >= delay) {
            move();
            draw();
            start = new Date().getTime();
        }
        
        if(posit.y < endY)
            anim = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    }
    animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I would even go as far as saying that `translate` nor `beginPath` are necessary as `arc` takes an x and y to start. The translation seems useless.

Comment: Thank you! I too was wondering about the "translate". But your version works very nicely.

Comment: In playing with this, I notice that it will not work if the endX and endY values are lower than startX and startY; i.e. if the end point is north and/or west of the start point. Is there a way around this?